# Does the function execution time limited in smart contract?

Tags: solidity

When a call a function in a smart contract.
Does the execution time limit if there is an infinite loop in that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no limits to the execution time, and it's not measured at all. The main limiting factor is the gas usage: each operation you perform costs gas, and you have to pay for all the gas your transaction uses.

If you have an infinite loop, your transaction will run out of gas (there's a limit on how much gas a transaction can use) and revert.

Actual code execution is not very performant anyway, but the main wait time comes from waiting for your transaction to be mined.